# Can't set field after toggle

Tags: jquery

trying to set ticks to this field but it only cuases the toggle to collapse on every click no matter what.  If I remove the attempt to set the field value, toggle works fine.

```
$('#preContent').toggle();
if ($("#txtreference")) { 
    $("#txtreference").val(Date.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is an error that [you could see in the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) : `Date` (the constructor) doesn't have a `getTime` function.

Change

```
Date.getTime()
```

to

```
new Date().getTime()
```

or

```
Date.now()
```

As an aside, note that this test doesn't make sense :

```
if ($("#txtreference")) {
```

It always pass.

If you want to know if there's at least one element in the jQuery collection, use

```
if ($("#txtreference").length) {
```

But this test is useless : there's no error if you use `val` on an empty collection.